# Setting the default font from menu bar does not stick

Tags: fonts, menu-bar

I am running emacs 24.4.1 on Kubuntu 15.04 and when I open a new frame, Emacs' own default font (i.e. its default default font) is used as the font for that new font, rather than the default font that I have set <s>and saved.</s> So I have to set the default font again every time I open a new frame. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the *Options > Set Default Font...* from the menu bar to set the default font, you also need to hit on ***Options > Save Options*** when you are happy with the settings you changed using the menu bar.

Comment: I thought I had done that, but apparently I hadn't. Something else, like desktop-mode, must have been saving it only for my existing frames.